# How do i send my location online in android studio

Tags: android-studio, location

I'm a beginner to android studio. I'm trying to build an my project app that can send my location to another client with just one click. i.e through online server.

At first I'm trying to test if my button gets the latitude and longitude value from the LocationListener.

below is my mainActivity

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener, LocationListener {

    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    protected LocationListener locationListener;
    protected Context context;

    private String myLoc = " ";


    GoogleMap mMap;
    Button bShare;
    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    private static final double Shillong_Lat = 25.5667,
                                Shillong_Lng = 91.8833;
    private GoogleApiClient mLocationClient;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener mListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 1000, this);



        if (servicesOK() ){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            bShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bShare);
            bShare.setOnClickListener(this);

            if(initMap()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ready to map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gotoLocation(Shillong_Lat, Shillong_Lng, 15 );

                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Map not Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    }

    private void gotoLocation(double latitude, double longitude, float zoom) {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                latLng, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    public boolean servicesOK(){
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);


        if(isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            return true;
        }else if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {

            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }return false;
    }


    private boolean initMap() {
        if (mMap == null){
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                    (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        }



        return(mMap != null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Location changed: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        myLoc = GetAddressDetailed(latitude, longitude);




    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == R.id.bShare){


            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sent: " + myLat + ", " + myLon ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you started coding the server part yet? What language are you using for that?

Comment: not yet. im trying to connect my button to first just to check if it gets the Latitude and Longitude Value from onLocationChanged. Can u help pls. And Thank You for Your Responds

Comment: And I'll be using php. I Haven't started yet. @halfer

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? The Java code to make a HTTP request? Search for "Android HTTP call" for that. You can probably search for "Android HTTP JSON tutorial" to get material for the whole thing. However, you should probably make this question a bit more specific - if you are stuck on everything, then people won't know how to help.

Comment: @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId() == R.id.bShare){

   // I want to call onChangeLocation Here. So as to understand if my button gets the getLatitude n getLongitude from it. n make a Toast just as to check.
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sent: " + myLat + ", " + myLon ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that. If you wish to highlight this piece of code to readers, I suggest you add it to your question (using the edit button) and explain how it relates to what you are stuck on.

Comment: my friend got it fixed!! Thank u for the responds halfer